# Magento: Update cart quantity programmatically

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I am creating a magento extension. In which I want to update the item quantity in cart programmatically. I am using the following code to display the items in cart.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
  //Do something
}
```

What i want is to update the quantity on cart for a specific product. I know it can be done like this

```
$pid=15;
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
if($pid==$item->getId())
$item->setQty($qty);
}
```

But I don't like this method as it would go through each and every product to update the quantity of a single product. I wonder if there is a way to update the quantity in one line i:e without using for loop.

Comment: what event are you using?

Comment: check this : http://www.onlinecode.org/magento-update-cart-quantity/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the product_id, not the item_id right ?

If it's the case it's impossible to get the product id without performing the whole items.

Look at `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::getItemByProduct($product);` you'll see it performs the whole catalog.

Basically I'll do it like this :

```
//get Product 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
//get Item
$item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);

$quote->getCart()->updateItem(array($item->getId()=>array('qty'=>$qty)));
$quote->getCart()->save();
```

You should optimise this with some quick tricks :

```
$quote->hasProductId($pid) to check if product is in the cart
```

and

```
($qty!=$item->getQty())
```

to check if quantity is not already good...

Please note that it is untested code, and some kind of reflexions to help you find the solution, I didn't do the job for you.

Kind Regards,

Comment: If i have the item id then how can i do this?

Comment: If you have the item_id remove the 2 first lines, and replace it by $item= Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($item_id); and $pid = $item->getProductId();

Comment: i had to modify like this to get it to work: $quote->updateItem($itemId, array( 'qty' => $qty));

Comment: If the item has custom option, it will be error as you force update only qty

Comment: can you please let me know why I am getting this message - Call to a member function updateItem() on a non-object , I have copied your codes as it is.

Comment: Osify is right. You get error 'Please specify the product's option(s)' for any product that has required options, like size.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure it will work. Try this. It's save's my time.

```
public function updateCartAction(){
    $item_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');
    $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');

    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $quote->updateItem($item_id, array( 'qty' => $qty));
    $quote->save();
    echo "Sssssss";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution

```
  $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($cartid);
     $cartItems = $quote->getAllItems();
        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {

         if($cartiemid==$item->getId()){
             $item->setQty($qty);
             $item->save(); // you need to save the item after qty update
         }

        }
    $quote->save();
```